# A record is saving as two or more in the database in PHP

Tags: php, sql

A record is saving as two or more in the database. I couldn't find where the problem was.

```
if(isset($_POST['send_photo'])){
  if ($_FILES["gallery_photo"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") {
      $photo_name=$_FILES["gallery_photo"]["name"];
      $photo= explode(".", $photo_name);
      $extension=$photo[1];
      $new=md5($photo[0]);
      $newname="uploads/gallery/".$new.".".$extension;
 }
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gallery_photo"]["tmp_name"],$newname)) {
         $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO gallery (student_id, first_name, last_name, photo) VALUES ( '$student_id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$newname') ",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $query->execute(array($newname));
     }
}
```

```
 <form class="form"  method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h6>Photo...</h6>
                        <input type="file" name="gallery_photo" class="text-center center-block file-upload">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success " type="submit"  name="send_photo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Gönder</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Do you mean that your `INSERT` statement is being executed more than once?  Are you requesting it more than once?

Comment: when I click the button, the data should be saved once,But it is saved more @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO gallery (student_id, first_name, last_name, photo) VALUES ( '$student_id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$newname')");
```

and remove the execute line

Comment: Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 2 to be array, int given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery.php on line 22